# Having trouble with drawPanel creating grid

Tags: java, graphics, grid, user-input

Trying to make a grid of 2^n size, asking the user for 'n'. I haven't coded in the 2^n part, which is also a little confusing for me. But right now my board will not display correctly when I get input from the user. My drawLine is a diagonal line going through the whole board.

How do I get the board to be displayed correctly?

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
public class DrawingPanelTest2{

   public static void main(String args[]){

//        System.out.println("How big do you want your Tromino grid?");
//        System.out.println("Please enter a perfect power of 2.");
//        int size = stdin.nextInt();   

        //create a drawing panel of width=400px and height=400px
        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(400, 400);
        //set the background of the panel to CYAN
        panel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        //create a graphic object for the panel 
        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();

        //draw square
        drawFigure_1(g,0,0);

   }

   public static void drawFigure_1(Graphics g,int x, int y) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How big do you want your Tromino grid?");
          System.out.println("Please enter a perfect power of 2.");
          int size = stdin.nextInt(); 
        //set your drawing color to red
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            //draw a rectangle, (x,y) is the top-left cordiante of the rectangle, and ((i*z), (i*z)) 
            //are the width and height of the rectangle
            g.drawRect(x, y, i * size, i * size);
            g.drawLine(x, y, i *size, i *size);
        }
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This `Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();` is not how custom painting is done.

This `Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);` is not how you should interacting with the user from within the context of GUI

Start by taking a look at [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Take a look at the [`Graphics` Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html)

`Graphics#drawRect` takes 4 parameters, the `x`, `y` position (top left corner) and the `width` and `height` of the rectenagle, whereas `Graphics#drawLine` takes `x1`, `y1`, which is the start point and `x2`, `y2` which is the end point.

So you want to draw a horizontal line, you need to use something more like `g.drawLine(x, y, i * size, i);` or for a vertical line, something more like `g.drawLine(x, y, i, i * size);`

If you are trying to draw a grid, then you will need loops, one horizontal and one vertical.  You will also need to update the `x`/`y` of each rectangle, so that they are placed corrected, so rather than modifying the size parameters, you should be modifying the position parameters

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class myjava{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double pw = input.nextDouble();
        myPan panel = new myPan(pw);
        JFrame application = new JFrame();
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.add(panel);           
        application.setSize(400, 400);
        application.setVisible(true); 
    }
}

class myPan extends JPanel{
    public double pow;
    public myPan(double p){
        pow = p;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        double num = Math.pow(2,pow);
        double across;
        double up;
        if(pow % 2 == 0){ //is a square
            System.out.println("square");
            across = Math.pow(num,0.5);
            up = across;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("not");
            double x = Math.floor(pow/2);
            double y = x + 1;
            across = Math.pow(2,x);
            up = Math.pow(2,y);
        }
        System.out.println(across);
        System.out.println(up);
        //
        //
        double wid = 400/across; //width of one
        double hi = 400/up; //height of one
        double nowX = 0;
        double nowY = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < up; i++){ //top to bottom
            nowX = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < across; j++){
                //System.out.print("*");
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawRect((int)nowX, (int)nowY, (int)wid, (int)hi);
                nowX = nowX + wid;
            }
            nowY = nowY + hi;
            //System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here now that I have this, I have a tromino puzzle program coded up but was in need of combining what I have with the graphics. This is what has been getting to me, I am almost done. Could you have a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19717359/tromino-program-using-graphics